# Basic getName function for a constructor function wrong

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a new constructor function called Cat, which takes in a cat's name. I want the Cat to have several methods, including a getName and setName method.

If I execute 
`cat = new Cat('Catarina');`

and then run `cat.getName();` I'm expecting "Catarina" to be returned but instead am getting `undefined`.

JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/cuteye/edit?js,console

```
function Cat(name) {

    function getName() {
        return name;
      }

    function setName(name) {
      this.name = name;
     }

}
```

Comment: you'll need to set `name` to `this.name` in your constructor, then have `getName` return `this.name`

Answer (score 0):

This should work as expected:

```
function Cat (name) {
    this.name = name;
}    
Cat.prototype.getName = function () {
    return this.name;
}
Cat.prototype.setName = function (name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

More about class creation: https://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/

Answer (score -1):

You are creating a Closure. You need to return the methods or they stay private.

```
function Cat(name) {

        this.name = name;

        function getName() {
            return name;
          }

        function setName(name) {
          this.name = name;
         }

         return {
            getName : getName,
            setName : setName
         }        
}

cat = new Cat('Catarina');
console.log(cat.getName());
```